# Instagram python requests log in without API

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to log into instagram without the use of the API but recieve a 403 response? Credentials are correct but still getting the response. Any help on this matter?

```
import requests

main_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'
login_url = main_url+'accounts/login/'
user_agent = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A523 Safari/8536.25'

session = requests.session()
session.headers = {"user-agent": user_agent}
session.headers.update({'Referer': main_url})

req = session.get(main_url)
session.headers.update({'set-cookie': req.cookies['csrftoken']})
print(req.cookies['csrftoken'])
print(req.status_code)

login_data = {"username": "<user>", "password": "<pass>"}


login = session.post(login_url, data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)
print(login.cookies['csrftoken'])
print(login.status_code)
session.headers.update({'set-cookie': login.cookies['csrftoken']})

cookies = login.cookies

print(login.headers)
print(login.status_code)
```

Comment: I tried this one, and works. You can follow this code.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51272575/11976347

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) states the following:

> **403 Forbidden**

> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood
> the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that wishes to
> make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that
> reason in the response payload (if any).

> If authentication credentials were provided in the request, **the
> server considers them insufficient to grant access**.  The client
> SHOULD NOT automatically repeat the request with the same
> credentials.  The client MAY repeat the request with new or different
> credentials.  However, a request might be forbidden for reasons
> unrelated to the credentials.

So it looks like server will not allow you to access desired data without using official API.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with your code, and as is, it does indeed return a 403.

However, it can be fixed by adding a **csrfmiddlewaretoken** property to the data variable sent in your POST request. Change the line in your code from:

```
login_data = {"username": "<user>", "password": "<pass>"}
```

to

```
login_data = {"csrfmiddlewaretoken": req.cookies['csrftoken'], "username": "<user>", "password": "<pass>"}
```

Also, add a `/ajax` to the end of your `login_url` variable. Otherwise it won't authenticate.

It'll give you a 200 code after that. Good luck!