# I cant login instagram using requests

Tags: python, authentication, beautifulsoup, python-requests, instagram

I find [How would I log into Instagram using BeautifulSoup4 and Requests, and how would I determine it on my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62826727/how-would-i-log-into-instagram-using-beautifulsoup4-and-requests-and-how-would) this
but code

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from datetime import datetime

link = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
login_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'

time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())

payload = {
    'username': 'login',
    'enc_password': f'#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{time}:your_password',
    'queryParams': {},
    'optIntoOneTap': 'false'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(link)
    csrf = re.findall(r"csrf_token\":\"(.*?)\"", r.text)[0]
    r = s.post(login_url, data=payload, headers={
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Referer": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/",
        "x-csrftoken": csrf
    })
    print(r.status_code)
```

gives me error with csrftoken

```
      line 21, in <module>
    csrf = re.findall(r"csrf_token\":\"(.*?)\"", r.text)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and other posts on Stack Overflow don't work for me

I dont want use Selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

Add a [user-agent](https://generate-name.net/user-agent) to your get request header on line 20:

```
r = s.get(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X 10_7_3 rv:3.0; sl-SI) AppleWebKit/533.38.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0 Safari/533.38.2'})
```

---

## Long answer

If we look at the error message you posted, we can start to dissect what's gone wrong. Line 21 is attempting to find a **csrf_token** attribute on the [instagram login page](https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/).

### Diagnostics

We can see from the error message that the list index is out of range, which in this case means that the list returned by `re.findall` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)) is empty. This means that either

1. Your regex is wrong
2. The html returned by your get request ([docs](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_get.asp)) `r = s.get(link)` on line 20 doesn't contain a **csrf_token** attribute
3. The attribute doesn't exist in the source html

If we visit the page and look at its html source, we can see that a csrf_token attribute is indeed present on line 261:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"config":{"csrf_token":"TOKEN HERE","viewer":null,"viewerId":null}}</script>
```

Note, I have excluded the rest on the code for brevity.

Now that we know it's present on the page, we can write the scraped html that you're receiving via your get request to a local file and inspect it:

```
r = s.get(link)
with open("csrf.html", "w") as f:
   f.write(html)
```

If you open that file and do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for **csrf_token**, it's not present. This likely means that Instagram detected that you're accessing the page via a scraper and returned a modified version of the page.

### The fix

In order to fix this, you need to add a user-agent to your request header which essentially 'tricks' the page into thinking you're accessing it via a browser, This can be done by by changing:

```
r = s.get(link)
```

to something like this:

```
r = s.get(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X 10_7_3 rv:3.0; sl-SI) AppleWebKit/533.38.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0 Safari/533.38.2'})
```

Note, this is a random user agent from [here](https://generate-name.net/user-agent).

---

### Notes

I appreciate that you don't want to use selenium for your task, but you might find that the more dynamic interactions you want to do, the harder it is to achieve it with static scraping libraries like the requests module. Here are some good resources for learning selenium in python:

[Selenium docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

[Python Selenium Tutorial #1 - Web Scraping, Bots & Testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xjv1sY630Uc)